# Referencing svg icon from library's assets using angular-svg-icon component

Tags: angular, svg, icons, angular-library

I've got an angular project where there's an extra library to it. The library is part of the sources. The main app AND the library both have assets, both display SVG icons from the assets directory. I'm using the module `angular-svg-icon` to display those SVG images.

The problem is, that whereas the library displays an icon the right way, I'm trying to display the very same icon from the main app and I couldn't find out the right path for the icon. I don't know what `angular-svg-icon` does because it's not exactly documented.

Path to the library's assets and that specific icon: `projects/projectX/src/assets/icons/iconA.svg`.

So as I said, the icon gets display in the library in a component, but not in another component of the main app.

I'm using this code in the library AND in the main app:

```
<svg-icon src="assets/icons/iconA.svg"></svg-icon>
```

How should I reference the icon?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out the solution.

The solution was to debug the `angular-svg-icon` source code at runtime.

I set some breakpoint where it never ran into. So I decided the module doesn't get loaded the right way. So it must be something with the module loading mechanism first.

After I added the missing module in `app.module.ts` the icon finally got displayed without even changing the icon's path.

```
imports: [
  ...
  AngularSvgIconModule,
```

So now, the following works:

```
<svg-icon src="assets/icons/iconA.svg"></svg-icon>
```

I have to add that I've got the following in `angular.json` to catch the library's assets into the target package:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "assets": [
          ...
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "projects/projectX/src/assets/",
            "output": "/assets"
          }
        ],
```